# Adding custom property to all Application Insight traces

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I want to add a custom property to all traces in Application Insights.

In Asp.Net Core I've added this code

```
internal class TelemetryProperties : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private IConfiguration configuration;

    public TelemetryProperties(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    // TODO: Not being added to all traces.
    // http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/01/telemetry-initializers/
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var applicationName = configuration["Application:Name"];
        telemetry.Context.Properties.Add("Application", applicationName);
    }
}
```

and in the configure method of Startup.cs I have added:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new TelemetryProperties(Configuration));
```

The intent was to add "Application" to all traces, even ones made automatically by Application Insights, but the effect is that it is ONLY being added to my custom traces that Im calling through my code.

How do I add a property to ALL traces, even ones I do not create.

Edit: The purpose of this is that I want to have multiple APIs in the same application insights log, but I want to be able to partition when neccessary by adding a defining property such as application name.

Comment: for the all traces, does it include the request call? and your custom traces, you mean you call the method trackTrace()?

Comment: I want it to be added to all traces, including the exception traces that Application  Insights adds all on its own without me doing anything

Answer (score 1):

Modifying TelemetryConfiguration.Active is not the recommended approach in Asp.Net Core apps. Can you add the telemetry initializer using the below code in `ConfigureServices` ?

`services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryProperties>();`

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration#adding-new-telemetryinitializer

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used your code(without change), and at my side, all the traces(the application insights adds, I didn't use any Trackxx methods) including the exception all have the property "Application". Please see the screenshots below:
[image]

If it still occurs in your side, please provide the screenshots of the appInsights' logs.